# how to start kube-apiserver which installed by kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

Today I found the master kubernetes v1.21 node kube-apiserver was ended. Now I tried to use this command to startup the kube-apiserver:

```
[root@k8smasterone kubernetes]# systemctl start kube-apiserver
Failed to start kube-apiserver.service: Unit not found.
```

The cluster was installed by kubeadm, I did not found the kube-apiserver service config in the host folder `/etc/systemd/system` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. what should I do to start the kube-apiserver service? I tried to use kubeadm to start the kube-apiserver service but did not found any docs to guide this action.

Comment: Kube-apiserver is a static pod and its monitored by kubelet in master node.  if the static pod fail its kubelet responsibility to restart it.  you can check kubelet logs and see if there are errors.  its not a systemd process so it cant be started using systemctl.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/#constants-and-well-known-values-and-paths

Comment: if could not start by systemctl, how to start it? the control plane process not running. using the `kubeadm init` command? it look like will erase the legacy pod. I want to keep all my pod of the cluster.

Comment: It looks like I should use the kubelet to startup the other compoent, but I have lost the legacy kubelet service config after reinstall the kubelet.